# How to find a folder by name in Google Drive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I want to continue to place file for an ios app in the same subdirectory beneath root of the user's drive.

I can create a new folder, create files within that new folder, but I don't want to be responsible for persisting the id of the folder I initially create into eternity.  There has to be a way to rediscover the same directory and continue to place within that.  The API doesn't seem to allow for it however.  If I get a query that returns an array of [`GTLDriveChildReference`](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/reference/ios-client/interface_g_t_l_drive_child_reference)'s there doesn't seem to be a title field with which to compare against the title of the directory I want to place my files in.

```
[GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];
query.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed=false";
[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler::^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                        GTLDriveChildList *children,
                                        NSError *error) {
  if (nil == error) {
    for (GTLDriveChildReference *child in children) {
      NSLog(@"File Id: %@", child.identifier);
    }
  } else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it for a recent project, where I needed a folder called 'new'

```
func getFolderNewID()
{
    // return the ID of the 'new' folder
    // create it if it's not there         
    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesList()
    query.q = "'root' IN parents and title = 'new' and trashed = false"

    googleDrive.service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinishSelector: "returnedFolderForNew:finishedWithObject:error:")
}

func returnedFolderForNew(ticket : GTLServiceTicket, finishedWithObject response : GTLDriveFileList, error : NSError?)
{

    if let _ = error
    {
        return
    }


    if response.items() == nil
    {
        // nothing returned - go create a folder
        createFolderNew()
        return
    }

    for fileItem in response.items()
    {
        googleDrive.folderNew = fileItem.identifier!!
    }
}
```

Once you have that fileItem.identifier, you can use that in query, to check for identifier in parents

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API client for iOS should still be able to filter out queries because of Drive's [query language](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) you can specify the mimeType to be folder and query using its name.